# Creating MIDI files on the fly using Audiokit

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

I'm currently using the following method to play stems in a song:

1. Load stem_01.mp3 into AKAudioFile
2. Add AKAudioFile to AKMIDISampler
3. Add AKMIDISampler to AKMixer
4. repeat 1-3 for number of stems
5. Create AKSequencer using custom MIDI file: This MIDI file has a separate track for each stem in the song. There is one note on each track in the MIDI file (on C3) that lasts for the duration of the song.
6. I add a new track to the AKSequencer for each stem, and use the sequencer to control playback of the stems

My question is this: is there any way to automate the creation of this MIDI file. I know the number of stems, and the duration of the song; can I dynamically create the MIDI file that Audiokit requires to enable AKSequencer?

Any thoughts or ideas on this most welcome, as it would save a lot of manual work when adding new songs.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for pure automation or something like a macro? Haven't used this before, but it is an intresting problem

Comment: @IBXCODECAT ... pure automation is the dream, so that any audio files can be used, and most importantly made to loop (with given duration, playback goes back to the start again and again until playback stops)...

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it

Comment: @IBXCODECAT - ha a year later, and I'm looking at this again. Did you have any further thoughts on this? Thanks indeed